# Is there an example of the Builder Pattern in the .NET BCL?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

Is there an example of the full builder pattern in the .NET base class library? I'm looking for something that has an actual director and multiple concrete builders.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm far from an expert in this area, but I *think* that [DbCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommandbuilder.aspx) and its inheriting classes ([OdbcCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommandbuilder.aspx), [OleDbCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder.aspx), [SqlCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx)) might be an example...if it's OK that the abstract builder base class also serves as the director.  The various concrete classes delegate to their base class, which then calls methods like these (per Reflector):

```
private DbCommand BuildDeleteCommand(DataTableMapping mappings, DataRow dataRow)
{
    DbCommand command = this.InitializeCommand(this.DeleteCommand);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int parameterCount = 0;
    builder.Append("DELETE FROM ");
    builder.Append(this.QuotedBaseTableName);
    parameterCount = this.BuildWhereClause(
        mappings, dataRow, builder, command, parameterCount, false);
    command.CommandText = builder.ToString();
    RemoveExtraParameters(command, parameterCount);
    this.DeleteCommand = command;
    return command;
}
```

This fulfills some of the requirements to be a builder:

- abstract builder class
- concrete builder classes
- complex multi-step building in the various DbCommandBuilder methods (`BuildDeleteCommand`, `BuildInsertCommand`, `BuildUpdateCommand`)
- product (`DbCommand`, cast to a specific command type by the concrete classes) which is more complex than just a SQL string, because it has a timeout, a command type, potentially a transaction, etc.

But there's not a separate class serving as the director; in effect, the `DbCommandBuilder` base class is the director.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple concrete builders? Not that I know of unless you count [`WebRequest.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.create.aspx) which is a pretty trivial kind of building.

[`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) and [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) are both reasonable as simple "one builder" examples though.

Comment: WebRequest.Create is a factory method, not a builder. You can't pass it a FTP url and get back an HTTPWebRequest.

Comment: I actually have those other two classes marked down in my notes as examples of the "common builder" pattern. For this version I tried using the SOAP and Binary Formatters, but alas they seem to be missing the director component.